# set size to responsive iframe in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

Is it possible to set a size to an inframe in bootstrap?

I set up the iframe like this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="…"></iframe>
</div>
```

And I tried to set a maximum height to 450 px with this:

```
.embed-responsive {
   max-height:450px;
}
```

This had no effect at all. Can you give me a hint, how could achieve a smaller but still responsive iframe?

Comment: Have you tried additionally setting height of the iframe? `.embed-responsive iframe { height:100%; }`.

Comment: This worked for the iframe and the embedded video: `.embed-responsive, .embed-responsive iframe, .embed-responsive-16by9, .embed-responsive-item { 
   max-width: 800px;
   max-height:450px; 
}`

 But the surrounding div keeps the 100% height, so I have a huge blank area below the iframe.

Comment: I set a new `<div style="video-max-size">` around the whole thing. It is defined as: `.video-max-size {
   max-width: 800px;
   max-height:450px; 
}` That does the trick for me.

Answer (score 21):

I've had the same problem and solved it by adding a row and col-sm-8 (according to what size you'd like) around the .embed-responsive div.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="responsive-embed-16by9-iframe-youtube">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really a good idea. I think I can use this on other occasions too.
Thanks!

Comment: I am new to Bootstrap, but aren't rows always supposed to add up to 12?

Comment: Yes, although it does work in the example I've provided here. To be more semantically correct you would add a <div class="col-sm-4"> after the closing of the col-sm-8. You could check out shoelace.io to find out how cols behave.

Comment: It will control only width of video. What about height? Height will remain big and unproportional.

Comment: There is a typo, in the `class` here: `<div class="bs-example" data-example-id="responsive-embed-16by9-iframe-youtube">`

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 use `class='embed-responsive'` instead of `class='embed-responsive-item'`. It should work better. [Source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/embed/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add how many columns it should cover. Here I defined as 4 columns. (Note: Bootstrap a whole screen consists of 12 cells.)

```
<div class="bs-example col-sm-4" data-example-id="responsive-embed-16by9-iframe-youtube">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```